Notification Data Doesn't Sent
So I created a small project which can send notifications using service-worker, notification API & push API, but after filling in the title, description, button title 1 and 2 and submitting, the notification can appear but there is no callback like the action performed on the notification (such as clicking 1 or 2 buttons or just clicking on the notification, even though there is no error, the service worker has been registered, there is nothing wrong with the service worker, there is nothing wrong with the code to send notifications. Does anyone know where the problem is?
service-worker.js


self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {

    event.notification.close();



    if (event.action === 'button-1') {

        console.log('Tombol ' + '"' + event.notification.actions[0].title + '"' + ' Diklik. / Tombol ' + event.action + ' Diklik.');

        event.waitUntil(clients.matchAll().then(clients => {

            clients.forEach(client => {

                client.postMessage({ var: 'notification-data', action: 'Mengklik Tombol "' + event.notification.actions[0].title + '"', title: event.notification.title, desc: event.notification.body });

            });

        }));

    } else if (event.action === 'button-2') {

        console.log('Tombol ' + '"' + event.notification.actions[1].title + '"' + ' Diklik. / Tombol ' + event.action + ' Diklik.');

        event.waitUntil(clients.matchAll().then(clients => {

            clients.forEach(client => {

                client.postMessage({ var: 'notification-data', action: 'Mengklik Tombol "' + event.notification.actions[0].title + '"', title: event.notification.title, desc: event.notification.body });

            });

        }));

    } else {

        console.log('Hanya Notifikasi Saja Yang Diklik.');

        event.waitUntil(clients.matchAll().then(clients => {

            clients.forEach(client => {

                client.postMessage({ var: 'notification-data', action: 'Hanya Mengklik Notifikasi', title: event.notification.title, desc: event.notification.body });

            });

        }));

    }

});

index.html (scripts)



          if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('https://aio-website.netlify.app/worker/service-worker.js').then(function (registration) {
                    console.log("[Service-Worker] Registered Successfully: \n" + registration.scope);
                }, function (err) {
                    console.error("[Service-Worker] Failed to Register : \n" + err);
                });
            });
        } else {
            Swal.fire({
  icon: "error",
  title: "Error",
  text: "Browser Ini Tidak Mendukung Service-Worker",
});
            console.warn("This Browser Does Not Support [Service-Worker]");
        }

       function requestNotificationPermission() {
            if ('Notification' in window) {
                Notification.requestPermission()
                    .then(function (permission) {
                        if (permission === 'granted') {
                            Swal.fire({
  icon: "success",
  title: "Sukses",
  text: "Akses Notifikasi Diizinkan",
}).then((result) => {sendNotification()});
                            console.log("Notification Access Allowed");
                            
                        } else {
                            Swal.fire({
  icon: "error",
  title: "Error",
  text: "Akses Notifikasi Ditolak",
});
                            console.warn("Notification Access Denied");
                        }
                    });
            } else {
                Swal.fire({
  icon: "error",
  title: "Error",
  text: "Browser Ini Tidak Mendukung API Notifikasi",
});
                console.warn("This Browser Does Not Support NOTIFICATION.API");
            }
        }

async function sendNotification() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && 'PushManager' in window) {
  let title;
let desc;
let btn1;
let btn2;

  // Tampilkan Swal untuk judul notifikasi
  title = await Swal.fire({
    title: "Judul Notifikasi",
    input: "text",
    inputLabel: "Ketik Disini...",
    inputValidator: (value) => {
      if (!value) {
        return "Wajib Diisi";
      }
    },
  });

  // Tampilkan Swal untuk deskripsi notifikasi
  desc = await Swal.fire({
    title: "Deskripsi Notifikasi",
    input: "text",
    inputLabel: "Ketik Disini...",
    inputValidator: (value) => {
      if (!value) {
        return "Wajib Diisi";
      }
    },
  });

  // Tampilkan Swal untuk judul tombol 1
  btn1 = await Swal.fire({
    title: "Judul Tombol 1",
    input: "text",
    inputLabel: "Ketik Disini...",
    inputValidator: (value) => {
      if (!value) {
        return "Wajib Diisi";
      }
    },
  });

  // Tampilkan Swal untuk judul tombol 2
  btn2 = await Swal.fire({
    title: "Judul Tombol 2",
    input: "text",
    inputLabel: "Ketik Disini...",
    inputValidator: (value) => {
      if (!value) {
        return "Wajib Diisi";
      }
    },
  });


                console.log('Judul Notifikasi Diubah Ke : ' + title.value);
                console.log('Deskripsi Notifikasi Diubah Ke : ' + desc.value);
                console.log('Judul Tombol-1 Diubah Ke : ' + btn1.value);
                console.log('Judul Tombol-2 Diubah Ke : ' + btn2.value);
            
      navigator.serviceWorker.ready
        .then(function (registration) {
          const options = {
            body: desc.value,
            icon: 'https://aio-website.netlify.app/assets/favicons/favicon.png',
            actions: [
              { action: 'button-1', title: btn1.value },
              { action: 'button-2', title: btn2.value }
            ]
          };
          registration.showNotification(title.value, options);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          Swal.fire({
            icon: "error",
            title: "Error",
            text: error,
              });
          console.error(error);
        });
  } else {
    Swal.fire({
  icon: "error",
  title: "Error",
  text: "Browser Ini Tidak Mendukung API Notifikasi &/(dan / atau) Service-Worker",
});
    console.error("This Browser Does Not Support NOTIFICATION.API &/(or / and) [Service-Worker]");
  }
}

        navigator.serviceWorker.onmessage = event => {
            if (event.data.var === 'notification-data') {
                Swal.fire({
  icon: "info",
  title: "Data Notifikasi",
  html: "Judul Notifikasi : <span id=\"1\"></span>\n Deskripsi Notifikasi : <span id=\"2\"></span>\n Aksi : <span id=\"3\"></span>",
  footer: "",
  didOpen: () => {
    Swal.getPopup().getElementById('1').textContent = event.data.title;
    Swal.getPopup().getElementById('2').textContent = event.data.desc;
    Swal.getPopup().getElementById('3').textContent = event.data.action;
  }
});
              console.log([{"Judul Notifikasi": event.data.title,
                           "Deskripsi Notifikasi": event.data.desc,
                           "Aksi": event.data.action}]);
            }
   
                  }

